# Servering React files in Express and Node on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I know there are a bunch of tutorials and posts about the MERN stack but I can't seem to deploy the front end react correctly. The backend handles the API requests correctly as it works on postman.

I have an express.static path to the client/build folder. Is the path to the react build folder incorrect or is there something else I should look into?

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0WeL.png)

Here is my server.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const Data = require("./data");
const path = require("path");

require("dotenv").config();

const API_PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const router = express.Router();

// this is our MongoDB database
// connects our back end code with the database
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true });

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once("open", () => console.log("connected to the database"));

// checks if connection with the database is successful
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

// (optional) only made for logging and
// bodyParser, parses the request body to be a readable json format
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger("dev"));

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello world");
});


// append /api for our http requests
app.use("/api", router);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
// launch our backend into a port
app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

Comment: If you are getting an error could you please edit your answer and add the error to it? It is very difficult to trace the faulty code without an error.

Comment: There isn't an error message. The front end is just not appearing. I did heroku logs and I'm only getting 200s.

Answer (score 0):

You have already defined your static file folder in the express middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));
```

So try changing the `res.sendFile()` method to look like this:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
```